# Why update Behaviour Subject function does not work

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, behaviorsubject

```
updateSubject() {
  this.value = false;
  this.howToUseObservables();
}
```

this function it fire when I press on button but Behavior subject doesn't fire .next as expected why ?

```
  value = true;
  constructor() {
    this.howToUseObservables().subscribe(ress => alert('in home ' + ress));

  }
  updateSubject() {
    this.value = false;
    this.howToUseObservables();
  }

  updateInOninle(subject: BehaviorSubject<any>) {
    subject.next('from func online');
  }
  updateInOffline(subject: BehaviorSubject<any>) {
    subject.next('from func offline');
  }
  howToUseObservables(): BehaviorSubject<any> {
    const testSubjec: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject('test');
    if (this.value === true) {
      this.updateInOninle(testSubjec);
    } else {
      this.updateInOffline(testSubjec);

    }
    return testSubjec;
  }
```

Comment: What makes you say that it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You might be thinking that since you've `alert`ed out the response from the `howToUseObservables` `BehaviorSubject<any>`, it will run even when the button click and you would be able to see the `alert` every time you click the button.

That that won't happen coz, you're returning a new `BehaviorSubject<any>` from the `howToUseObservables`. So unless you `subscribe` to the new `BehaviorSubject`, you won't see the `in home from func offline` being alerted out.

Try `subscribe`ing to the `return`ed `BehaviorSubject` in the `updateSubject` and you will see the response being logged on to the console.

```
updateSubject() {
  this.value = false;
  this.howToUseObservables()
    .subscribe(ress => console.log('in home ' + ress));
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-observables-work?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: yes , it worked as you expected , but why   constructor() {
    this.howToUseObservables().subscribe(ress => alert('in home ' + ress));

  }
doesn't fire , because I already subscribe in this.howToUseObservables function

Comment: You're `subscribe`ing to the `BehaviorSubject` returned from `howToUseObservables`. `howToUseObservables` returns a new `Observable` every single time. That's why your `subscription` will not fire after the first go inside your `constructor`.